# What should I do to make the color of the Kendoui column chart gradient

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

One of my current projects has a requirement to make the color of the column chart a gradient. I know how to change the color of the column chart, but I don't know if the color value can be like the background. Can I use the gradient?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you tried to include an image of something but messed up.  Can you edit your question so we can see whatever this image is you mean to share?  Thanks!

Comment: I am here for the first time to ask questions, so it seems to be released for the time being....

Answer (score 1):

There is an overlay option with which you can set a predefined gradient overlay:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/Overlay/

It should also be possible to add any gradient with a custom visual:

```
public visual(e: any): any {
  const visual = e.createVisual();
  const color = e.options.color;
  const gradient = new LinearGradient({
    start: [0, 0.5],
    end: [1, 0.5],
    stops: [{
      offset: 0.2,
      color: color,
      opacity: 0.5
    }, {
      offset: 0.5,
      color: color,
      opacity: 0.3
    }, {
      offset: 1,
      color: color,
      opacity: 0.1
    }]
  });

  visual.children[0].fill(gradient);

  return visual;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AFcM2Q9HAtNs1MhwWFu7?p=preview